# Does putting vegetables next to each other cause a conflict?

Tags: vegetables, growth, resources

I have a school project related to farming. For this project I should grow some vegetables in an indoor application.

And let say I have to grow them in a big container in the same soil and next to each other.

Does this cause any harm at all to the vegetables?

Should I make an advanced research for all combinations?

I am planning to grow some of following plants:

- Carrots
- Broccoli
- Garlic greens
- Lettuce
- Ginger
- Cucumber
- Spinach
- Chard
- Arugula

Also I appreciate if you provide any source about that issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I would say there will be no problems.

In general it is better not to repeat the same family of vegetables on the same spot (depletion of soil), and better not to have same families together (diseases).

Some combination are nice because of different growth rates (greens between slow growing vegetables, helps keeping away weeds, and keeping moisture).

On my experience, tomatoes should not be put near beans, or tomato plant will have an excessive growth (green parts, but still producing tomatoes).

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your last sentence about tomatoes and beans? I would find it hard to believe that the beans really fix that much nitrogen that it makes the tomato plants leafier than normal.

Comment: @Philip but I think it is the reason. Two rows of tomatoes, the two plants near beans have a really much ticker steam, and much taller that other tomatoes. But I'm happy if some one other will do more experiments (and give own results).